# Notificaciones generadas desde Magento

Tags: php, push-notification, magento2, magento-1.9

Necesito automatizar ciertos procesos relacionados a una tienda virtual desarrollada con Magento, y me gustaría saber si existe alguna configuración que me permita arrojar notificaciones desde Magento a un host remoto especificado previamente

Por ejemplo, si un producto ha sido vendido, que se arroje una petición POST con la data mínima necesaria a un endpoint remoto, y en ese host remoto yo me encargaría de procesar la data a conveniencia

He trabajado con otras APIs de E-commerce, y por ejemplo en Mercadolibre puedes especificar un endpoint en donde quieres recibir notificaciones (y funciona), pero no he encontrado nada parecido en Magento

Un plugin podría ser útil también

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Quizá la mejor opción que se me ocurre es que crees un [plugin de magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Utiliza uno que se ejecute posterior al evento que deseas notificar, en el puedes hacer los http request que desees.

Comment: Pensé lo mismo al principio, pero hemos terminado solucionandolo usando un cron job que realice peticiones al endpoint de la api de magento que ofrece la misma informacion

Comment: Esto debería ser un comentario y una respuesta.